# How do you make text appear when mouse is hovering?

Tags: swift, macos

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make text appear when hovering over an element, in this case, an NSImage? The best example of what I'm talking about is when you hover over an application when it's in your dock and the name of it appears. Here's an image of what I'm talking about:

Text when hovering over doc

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `NSButton` which can be initialised with your `NSImage`. You just need to set the button `toolTip` property:

```
let button = NSButton(image: buttonImage, target: self, action: #selector(imageAction))
button.toolTip = "Image action info"
```